# C#, I want to display a DataTable in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

Here is my Code:
There are some new Rows in the DataGrid, but they are all empty. Or is there any other Methode I can use?

```
private void btnFill_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var url = string.Empty;
    using (var web = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        url = web.DownloadString(txtMainUrl.Text + "/sitemap.xml");
    }

    var dataTablesummary = new DataTable();
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(string));
    dataTablesummary.Columns.Add("Check", typeof(bool));

    var link = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < url.Length; i++)
    {
        char letter = url[i];

        if (url[i] == '<' && url[i + 1] == 'l' && url[i + 2] == 'o' && url[i + 3] == 'c' && url[i + 4] == '>')
        {
            i += 5;
            do
            {
                link += url[i];
                i++;
            } while (url[i] != '<');
            dataTablesummary.Rows.Add(link, true);
        }
        link = string.Empty;
    }
    gridAdditionalUrls.ItemsSource = dataTablesummary.AsDataView();
}
```

Comment: We need to see the xaml for the `DataGrid`. Is there any reason why you are using code behind?

Comment: Maybe use gridAdditionalUrls.Items.Refresh(); ? However i would suggest you to drop this approach and start to develop you application using MVVM pattern